# Picker item source using xamarin:

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding, picker

I'd like to implement a simple picker XAML, where when I choose a value from the picker  will be populated automatically (the data comes from firebase). Here is what I have:

view Model xaml:

```
  <Picker  HeightRequest="50" 
                 x:Name="AppoiPatientName" Title="Patient Name" FontSize="Large"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding AppointmentPatientName}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AllAppointment}"
                 ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding AppointmentPatientName}">
            </Picker>
```

file cs

```
var picker = new Picker { Title = "Patient Name" };
          picker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, "AllAppointment");
           picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "AppointmentPatientName");
          picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("AppointmentPatientName");
```

model view :

```
public void AllAppointment()
    {public void AllAppointment()
    {
        services = new AppintmentService();
        Schedules = services.getScheduleAppointment();
    }
        services = new AppintmentService();
        Schedules = services.getScheduleAppointment();
    }
```

services

```
public ObservableCollection<Appoitment> getScheduleAppointment()
    {
        var ScheduleData = firebaseClient
         .Child("$Specalists / 406707265 / Patients / 0 / Appointments")
         .AsObservable<Appoitment>()
         .AsObservableCollection();

        return ScheduleData;
    }
```

Comment: first, you do not need to define your Picker in both XAML and the code behind.   Do one or the other.  Second, you can only bind to **public properties**.  `AllAppointment` is not a C# property

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested,you should define the Picker either in Xaml or in code behind.

More importantly,the `ItemsSource` property: `AllAppointment` should be defined as public properties.Moreover,you should consider using the type `ObservableCollection`  as that helps get notified when something was added to this collection.

So Use the AllAppointment like below:

```
public ObservableCollection<AllAppointmentModel> AllAppointment { get; set; } 
= new ObservableCollection<AllAppointmentModel>();
```